# How to sort a python list of arbitrary strings like Excel Column Names?

Tags: python

E.g. I have:

```
x = ["Column a is...", "Column ab uses...", "Column b has..."]
```

then I need to get:

```
x = ["Column a is...", "Column b has...", "Column ab uses..."]
```

Comment: Why should `ab` come _after_ `b`?  It seems to be that based on text sorting the opposite should be happening.

Comment: Because Excel columns are enumerated like "A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, AB, ... AZ, BA, ..."

Comment: You should read up on "natural sort", which is the same problem but with numbers (e.g. wanting 10 to be after 2). In general, look at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column identifier is guaranteed to be the second whitespace delimited token in each string then:

```
x = ["Column a is...", "Column ab uses...", "Column b has..."]

def conv(s):
    n = 0
    for c in reversed(s.split()[1].lower()):
        n *= 26
        n += ord(c) - ord('a')
    return n

print(sorted(x, key=conv))
```

The *conv()* function takes the column identifiers and converts them into a value that can be used for natural sorting

**Output:**

```
['Column a is...', 'Column b has...', 'Column ab uses...']
```

Comment: Possibly i will generalize this to work with arbitrary whitespaces by identifying the position of the colnames in each string first, but this is good for me already. Thanks mate. :)